# Converting .swf to .mov or .m4v ios objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, flash, ios6, avfoundation

I am trying a demo project where i am bundling the test.swf file and converting it to .mov or .m4v using AVFoundation. But everytime i try i get the following Error Failed

Export Failed: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11838 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo=0x109a9a200 {NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation is not supported for this media.}

Here is my code to change the format

```
 AVURLAsset *videoAssetOriginal = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:videoURL];
//    NSLog(@"videoAssetOriginal %@",videoAssetOriginal);
    AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
//    NSString *outputPath;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
      NSString *outputPath =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"videoExport.m4v"]];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionTrackOriginal = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrackB = [[videoAssetOriginal tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] lastObject];

    [compositionTrackOriginal insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAssetOriginal.duration)  ofTrack:clipVideoTrackB atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    NSLog(@"mixComposition %@",mixComposition);
    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough]; // if i keep presetName :AVAssetExportPreset1280x720 then it will only original video is rotated and trimmed video is removed from the video... and if i keep AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough then it shows black screen

    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exporter.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputPath];
    videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputPath];

    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        switch ([exporter status])
        {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"Export Failed: %@", [exporter error]);
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Export canceled");
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                NSLog(@"Video Exported !");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }];
```

Comment: Have you tried with debugging using breakpoints?

Comment: yeah !! i tried and did the same before too but then i was converting mov to m4v which was working fine... even i am able to get the swf file in AVURLAsset but when i export it with these formats it fails to export

Comment: Oh actually, i have tried to converting `mov` to `mp4` which was [working fine.](http://d.pr/n/ovSb) Check it out.

Comment: Got new error !!Export Failed: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11823 "Cannot Save" UserInfo=0x109a93220 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Save, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try saving again.}

Comment: Can you [try this once?](http://d.pr/n/mVEm)

Comment: Working fine when i passed video url with mov format but when i passed video url with swf it gives ERROR      Failed:Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11828 "Cannot Open" UserInfo=0x109a6cf30 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media format is not supported., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open, NSURL=file/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0-64/Applications/93DEBD9B-6225-46FE-B5B7-CB94E9B8B387/SwfToMovDemo.app/test.swf, NSUnderlyingError=0x109d70bc0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12847.)"}

Comment: Then, it may not support to convert `swf` to required formats.

Comment: yeah !! No Worries ! i will find some other way.. Thanx for helping me out